# Error: Node error: {"code":-32015,"data":"Reverted 0x","message":"VM execution error."}

Tags: solidity, web3js, myetherwallet, nodejs

I deployed my smart contract on **Kovan Etherium testnet**. After that, I am trying to interact with smart contract methods using **web3 1.0.0**. Below is my node js code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var api = myapikey;
const testnet = 'https://kovan.infura.io/'+ api;
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(testnet))

function a (){
        const abi =[{ abi json}];
        var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,'0xf...');
        console.log(MyContract.address);
        console.log(MyContract.jsonInterface);
        MyContract.methods.buyCoordinator(1,'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/17/19/08/lotus-1205631_960_720.jpg','abc').call({from:'0x7...'},(error, result) => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(error);
        });
}

a();
```

It returns null and giving me the following error:

> Error: Node error: {"code":-32015,"data":"Reverted 0x","message":"VM
>   execution error."}
>       at Function.validate (/home/administrator/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:114:18)
>       at HttpProvider._callee$ (/home/administrator/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:708:61)
>       at tryCatch (/home/administrator/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/administrator/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/administrator/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/administrator/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
>       at _next (/home/administrator/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Can anybody tell me the meaning of this error? Where I am getting wrong? And how to confirm whether the smart contract has interacted or not?

Comment: I am getting this error on payable methods.

Answer (score 1):

use **send** and not **call**

myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]]).send(options[, callback])

> Send -> Will send a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method. Note this can alter the smart contract state.
>
> Call -> Will call a “constant” method and execute its smart contract method in the EVM without sending any transaction. Note calling can not alter the smart contract state.

and it also could need a "value" in option, if it is a payable function and  require ether

Comment: And how do you know that the method is not constant, when this dude hasn't posted the contract's code?

Comment: there is no payable constant method (see his comment). and actually the name of the method say that this is a transaction-method and not a query -method

Comment: And how do you know that the method is `payable`, when this dude hasn't posted the contract's code? (BTW, he doesn't specify a `value` field, so there's a pretty good chance that this method is in fact **not** `payable`).

Comment: Oh, I see you even wrote it yourself at the bottom of your answer... so again - how do you know that the method is payable?

Comment: this dude worte down in the comment section that he is getting this error on a payable method, "I am getting this error on payable methods. – Varsh yesterday"