# Error on view function call {'code': -32015, 'data': 'Reverted 0x', 'message': 'VM execution error.'}

Tags: solidity, web3.py, chainlink

I have a view function I'm trying to call on the kovan network with the following code. (You'll need an RPC_URL for the kovan network.)

The function is the [Chainlink historical price](https://docs.chain.link/docs/historical-price-data) view function. I should be able to pass it a `roundId` and get back the price data from the round. I am able to do this in solidity, but for some reason I'm having a hard time in web3.py

```py
import os
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(os.getenv('RPC_URL')))
address = '0x396c5E36DD0a0F5a5D33dae44368D4193f69a1F0'
abi = '[{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"description","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint80","name":"_roundId","type":"uint80"}],"name":"getRoundData","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint80","name":"roundId","type":"uint80"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"answer","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startedAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"updatedAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint80","name":"answeredInRound","type":"uint80"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"latestRoundData","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint80","name":"roundId","type":"uint80"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"answer","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startedAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"updatedAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint80","name":"answeredInRound","type":"uint80"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'
price_feed_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
price_feed_contract.functions.getRoundData(1).call()
```

This is *not* a payable function, so I should not have to use `send()` as deemed by this similar question.

[Error: Node error: {"code":-32015,"data":"Reverted 0x","message":"VM execution error."}](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70313/error-node-error-code-32015-datareverted-0x-messagevm-execution-e)

I end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 964, in call
    **self.kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1499, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(call_transaction, block_identifier=block_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 434, in call
    [transaction, block_identifier],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 153, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32015, 'data': 'Reverted 0x', 'message': 'VM execution error.'}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've written, the problem lies in the contract you're calling with those params.

You're getting round data from a proxy contract, which has a different round id than the aggregators themselves (they are phased in order to not cause issues when switching between different aggregator contracts, which could give a lower round id than previously returned).

To solve your issue, try using a different round id. The current round id for this contract is `18446744073709556747`, so getting data from this round will work:

```py
>>> price_feed_contract.functions.getRoundData(18446744073709556747).call()
[18446744073709556747, 1209967561, 1600117216, 1600117216, 18446744073709556747]
```